# Derivative of Energy function for image processing - Diffusion regularisation

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, image-processing

I'm working through a topic concerning diffusion regularisation.
The following energy function is given.

$$ E(\mathbf u) = (u - f)^2 + \lambda \mathbf{ |\nabla u |}^2 $$

I understand that $(u-f)^2$ is a term that we need, because we want our resulting image to be mostly the same, while the regularistion term $\lambda \mathbf{ |\nabla u |}^2$ should smooth out the noise.
I'm having problems understanding the derivative for the regularisation term though. It is given by:

$$  \frac{\delta \frac{1}{2} \mathbf{ |\nabla u |}^2 }{\delta \mathbf{u}} = -div(\mathbf{\nabla u}) = -\Delta u$$

Again, I understand that the Laplace operator is given by $div(\mathbf{\nabla u})$, but I don't see how the derivation ends up being the divergence. As far as I know the Laplace operator is the sum of all unmixed second partial derivatives, while $\nabla u$ should be a vector of the derivatives with respect to $\delta x$ and $\delta y$. How do you take the derivative with respect to $\delta u$?

Thanx for your help